# ArcMap 10.6; ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec()

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

While running a tool box (connectivity index) I am receiving an error at the end; `ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec()!`.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that a field name in your expression does not exist or is misspelled.  See [Error: ERROR 000539: Invalid field](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000023815)

If you are trying to run the raster calculator in ArcPy in 10.6, then the raster calculator is not exposed to ArcPy.  You will need to recode your script and use other available tools. See [How To: Perform raster calculation using ArcPy](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022418).